# Ranking objects within array immutably with same values having same rank

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which takes a leaderboard array (already sorted by highest to lowest total) and then assigns a rank to each object inside the array. If more than one item has the same total, then both items should have the same rank e.g:

- 1: 60
- 2: 55
- 2: 55
- 2: 55
- 5: 50

I originally attempted to do this with `map`, but it appears as though I can't refer to the previous updated object inside of the map function. In the snippet below you can see how objects 2 & 3 in the array have `rank: undefined`.

```js
function assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard) {
  return leaderboard.map((item, index) => {
    const { total } = item;
    if (index > 0 && total === leaderboard[index - 1].total) {
      return {
        rank: leaderboard[index - 1].rank,
        ...item,
      };
    }
    return {
      rank: index + 1,
      ...item,
    };
  });
}

const leaderboard = [
  { total: 60 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 50 }
];

console.log(`original`, leaderboard);

const newLeaderboard = assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard);

console.log(`updated`, newLeaderboard);
```

I am able to achieve the desired functionality using `forEach`, but it mutates the objects in the original array. Is there any way to do this either with `map` or by altering my `forEach` function? (Note that for some reason SO's code snippet shows the array as not mutating but if you inspect using your dev tools you can see that it is mutated).

```js
function assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard) {
  const newLeaderboard = [...leaderboard];
  leaderboard.forEach((item, index) => {
    const { total } = item;
    if (index > 0 && total === leaderboard[index - 1].total) {
      item.rank = leaderboard[index - 1].rank;
    } else {
      item.rank = index + 1;
    }
  });

  return newLeaderboard;
}

const leaderboard = [
  { total: 60 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 50 }
];

console.log(`original`, leaderboard);

const newLeaderboard = assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard);

console.log(`updated`, newLeaderboard);
```

Comment: `const newLeaderboard = [...leaderboard];` this only makes a shallow copy of the array, so all the objects inside are *literally* the same from the first array. Changing one changes the other. You need to clone the objects before modifying them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Shouldn't the rank of the last object be `3` and not `5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to achieve the desired functionality using forEach, but it mutates the objects in the original array

As soon as you alter `item` inside your loop, it will modify the original array.

> Is there any way to do this either with `map`?

Yes, there is! You can pull `rank` up as a closed over variable, and then increment it only if the current value is lower than the previous.

```js
function assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard) {
  let rank = 1;

  return leaderboard.map((item, index) => {
    const { total } = item;
    if (index > 0 && total < leaderboard[index - 1].total) {
      rank = index + 1
    }
    return {
      rank: rank,
      ...item,
    };
  });
}

const leaderboard = [
  { total: 60 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 55 },
  { total: 50 }
];

console.log(`original`, leaderboard);

const newLeaderboard = assignLeaderboardRanks(leaderboard);

console.log(`updated`, newLeaderboard);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the last item having a rank of 5 is intended, this is how most sports-based leaderboards work.

Comment: @GuerillaRadio well, you can change the +=1 to = index +1